# how to download partial content from remote video url in nodejs?

Tags: webserver, node.js, streaming, video-encoding, javascript

I have the following code to download a specific part (range) of a video using nodejs http.get(),

```
const fileUrl = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4'
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('https')
const fileName = 'video.mp4'
const options = {
hostname: 'https://www.example.com',
path: '/path/to/video.mp4',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
'range': 'bytes=0-444444', //the size I'm requesting is the first 444.4 kB of the video
}

const req = http.get(options)
req.on('response', (res) => {
console.log(res.headers) //just to see headers
})

req.on('response', (res) => {
let file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName)
let size
res.on('data', (chunk) => {
file.write(chunk)
size = fs.statSync(file.path).size
console.log(size)
})
})
```

the problem is when I set `'range'` header to `'range': 'bytes=0-anyValue'` the downloaded video can be played normally, but when I set `'range'` to `'range': 'bytes=[anyValue>0]-anyValue'` the downloaded video is corrupted and can't be played.

when `'range': 'bytes=0-anyValue'` incoming response headers are:

```
{

'content-length': '444445',

'content-range': 'bytes 0-444444/17449469',

'accept-ranges': 'bytes',

'last-modified': 'Tue, 07 May 2019 11:45:38 GMT',

etag: '"f13a255d30ef81d2abf8ba2e4fefc2fd-1"',

'x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs': 'md5:4e3127acff74ac20b52e1680a5e0779d',

'cache-control': 'public, max-age=2592000',

'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="Rim.Of.The.World.2019.720p.Trailer.mp4";',

'content-encoding': 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding',

'x-amz-request-id': 'tx0000000000000001bfccc-00602060b1-1b3f92b-default',

'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',

date: 'Sun, 07 Feb 2021 21:50:41 GMT',

connection: 'close'

}
```

and the downloaded video is playable

but when `'range': 'bytes=[anyValue>0]-anyValue` incoming response headers are

```
{

'content-length': '443890',

'content-range': 'bytes 555-444444/17449469',

'accept-ranges': 'bytes',

'last-modified': 'Tue, 07 May 2019 11:45:38 GMT',

etag: '"f13a255d30ef81d2abf8ba2e4fefc2fd-1"',

'x-amz-meta-s3cmd-attrs': 'md5:4e3127acff74ac20b52e1680a5e0779d',

'cache-control': 'public, max-age=2592000',

'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="Rim.Of.The.World.2019.720p.Trailer.mp4";',

'content-encoding': 'System.Text.UTF8Encoding',

'x-amz-request-id': 'tx00000000000000e8c5225-006020613d-1afef1a-default',

'content-type': 'application/octet-stream',

date: 'Sun, 07 Feb 2021 21:53:01 GMT',

connection: 'close'

}
```

and the downloaded video is CORRUPTED and NOT playable

What I'm I doing wrong?

and How to achieve my goal properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, wouldn't you need at least the first handful of bytes that include the video stream's header information?

Comment: @MarkStewart exactly, but I don't know how to download the first bytes and then merge them with the range I want to download originally.

Comment: Looks like Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#Data_streams says that one piece of metadata, the "moov atom" that contains information on length and location of video data can be at the beginning or end of the file!  Might make it difficult.

Comment: @MarkStewart So, what do you think I should do as a solution?

Comment: @MarkStewart let's say I got the metadata using ffmpeg or any other method, How do I download a specific PLAYABLE range of that video?

Comment: Sorry, beyond my expertise in that area.  I am somewhat familiar with hunting through file metadata but the MPEG-4 container spec is very flexible; hence complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do just what you asked using ffmpeg command line tool like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss [start timestamp] -i [video path or url] -t [duation] [outputname.mp4] or other format
```

in your case, in nodejs you should use **fluent-ffmpeg** module:

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const url = 'www.example.com/video.mp4'

ffmpeg(url).seekInput(30)      //cut from the first 30th second
        .duration(10)          //duration I want to cut 
        .output('video.mp4)    //output video name
        .run()                 //run the process
```